# ListView source isn't being updated from NavigationParameters

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, listview, xamarin

This is my code in my Xamarin Forms app which should populate the xaml ListView with the `Activities` List of `DetaledActivity` which is filled from the previous page. When I step through and debug the code, `_activities` contains a number of items, but they don't show up in the xaml page.

If I populate the list with items in the constructor for this page, then I can click on those cells but no text is showing up in them.

```
public class DetailedActivityPageViewModel : _ViewModelBase
{
    INavigationService _navigationService;
    public DetailedActivityPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);
        if (parameters.ContainsKey("properties"))
        {
            var localAcs = new List<DetailedActivity>();
            var properties = (Dictionary<string, object>)parameters["properties"];
            foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                if (prop.Value != null)
                    localAcs.Add(new DetailedActivity { Key = prop.Key.ToString(), Value = prop.Value.ToString() });
            }
            _activities = localAcs;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<DetailedActivity> _activities;
    public IEnumerable<DetailedActivity> Activities { get { return _activities; } set { SetProperty(ref _activities, value, "Activities"); } }
}


public class DetailedActivity
{
    public string Key;
    public string Value;
}
```

---

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Key}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Value}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using an `ObservableCollection` for `localAcs` instead of a `List`. With an `ObservableCollection`, the binding should be updated when elements are added or removed from the `ObservableCollection`. And you may need to set the `_activities` to the `localAcs' before adding the elements, e.g.:

```
public override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);
    if (parameters.ContainsKey("properties"))
    {
        var localAcs = new List<DetailedActivity>();
        _activities = localAcs;
        var properties = (Dictionary<string, object>)parameters["properties"];
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            if (prop.Value != null)
                localAcs.Add(new DetailedActivity { Key = prop.Key.ToString(), Value = prop.Value.ToString() });
        }
    }
}
```